# How to calculate time based on location in react native

Tags: time, react-native

How can I calculate time based on a different location's time in my react native app?
For example, user is in New York and I want to the app to convert the time user inserts and convert it based on another location's time (which is given in lat/long) and then send it to server to store in DB.
Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Just convert to UTC from start, as @manosim suggested. Any reason this is not an option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was to be able to change the date/time based on a location entered by user. I initially thought of using lat/long, but then I realized Google Places returns offsetFromUTC and I used date.getTimezoneOffset() to calculate the offset of user's device, and then calculated the time that should actually go into DB.

Answer (score 1):

Since by default `Date.now()` will give you the time based on the phone's timezone, I would suggest using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) which has a feature to get the UTC time (more on the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)).

The default use would be:

```
const now = moment();
```

And in order to avoid timezones and get the UTC time:

```
const now = moment.utc();
```

Comment: Where did you use lat/long?!

Comment: Well if you use .utc() then I do not see any reason for doing things with geolocation since the timezone of the user won't matter.